# How does passing an instance of one class to another work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

For a couple of days I've been attempting to pass an instance of a variable from one of my classes to another, and until recently I have not been able to get it to work. I've read [this document](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) regarding classes and instances, I've searched online and stackoverflow and I couldn't get an answer until I tried a solution from a previous asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172477/how-to-pass-value-of-entry-from-one-class-to-another-class) and it solved my problem. However, I'm not exactly sure on the *why* and the *how* it works.

My code goes as follows, :

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    main_window = Tk()
    app = First(main_window)
    main_window.mainloop()

class First:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title('First Window')

        self.entry1 = Entry(self.root)
        self.entry1.pack()

        btn = Button(self.root, text="click", command=self.clicked)
        btn.pack()
    def clicked(self):
        writeDoc(First=self)

class writeDoc:
    def __init__(self, First):
        self.First = First
        txt = self.First.entry1.get()
        print(txt)

if __name__ == '__main__'
    main()
```

Under the class `writeDoc` whenever I hover over the parameter `First` it is not a reference to the `Class First`, so I am unsure how it has  access to `entry1`. The same goes for the `First` within `writeDoc(First=self)`. Addtionally, why does `writeDoc(First=self)` work but not `writeDoc(self.First)`?

I assumed when I want to reference to another class and want to pass its instances over I would need to do

```
class First:
....
def clicked(self):
writeDoc(First)
....

class writeDoc(First):
    def __init__(self, First):
    super().__init__(First):
...
```

But, this didn't work for me at all.

I hope this isn't a loaded/jumbled question. I want to understand how this works to create better code and avoid misunderstanding how python classes works.

Comment: You're just confusing yourself by naming that parameter `First`.  It's *not* the same thing as the class named `First`; in fact, it is a specific instance of that class.  The convention in Python is to use capitalized names only for classes, and lowercase names (`first`, perhaps) for instances.

Comment: btw your `class writeDoc` seems not worth the effort of writing a class. From the code you provide, it would be less confusing to use a function like this: `def writeDoc(first): print(first.entry1.get())`

Comment: "Under the class writeDoc whenever I hover over the parameter First it is not a reference to the Class First" it's not, its a parameter, and you pass an *instance* of class First to it.

Comment: `writeDoc(First=self)` passes the instance to the `writeDoc` class initializer.

Comment: In the second case, you are trying to use inheritance, but that is absolutely *not necessary*.

Comment: Why do you think `writeDoc(self.First)` *should* work? This is in your `First` class definition, and `self` is an instance of `First`, why would it have a `.First` attribute?

Comment: @jasonharper thanks! This helps, a I will adjust to that convention for my code :) Probably find a new name for the instance to make things less confusing

Comment: @quamrana In this specific example you are right, it is not worth the effort. The objective for `writeDoc` is to be used to gather more entries and use docxtpl to write it on a doc. I needed to make a simple test case to see if I can get it to work before moving onto the real thing

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, this helps me understand it a bit better. Why would inheritance not be fully necessary? Thirdly, reading peoples comments made me realize I wasn't fully understanding inheritence, or at least wasn't doing it right. I thought `writeDoc(self.First)` would work due to needing to pass `First` due to having `writeDoc(First)`. But I was misunderstanding how to properly do it

Comment: @Avila because you don't need inheritance to pass arguments to functions or to use *composition*. Just remember, **everything is an object**, i.e. an instance of a class. This is no different than you doing something like `def __init__(self, val):` and then `self.val = val` and passing an `int` to the constructor. `MyClass(val=1)`. Nothing special is needed, inheritance has nothing to do with it. You didn't have to inherit from `int` to do that, i.e. `class MyClass(int): ...`... you just passed the argument to the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `clicked()` method, `self` refers to an instance of the `First` class. It then does

```
writeDoc(First=self)
```

which passes that instance to the `writeDoc` class's `__init__()` method, as the value of its `First` parameter. This is no different from passing any other object as a method parameter.

`writeDoc(self.First)` doesn't work because there's no `First` attribute in the `self` instance. `First` is the name of the class, not an attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much. You alongside everyone else made this a lot more understandable for me